# Rails model definition using related field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that is multi-tenant.  In the Tenant record, I store codes that are particular to that Tenant.

The following works well (PS - scope doesn't work):

```
class Worequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tenant(:tenant)

  def self.closed
   where("statuscode_id = ?", ActsAsTenant.current_tenant.request_closed)
  end
```

What I really need is not `worequest.statuscode_id` but instead `worequest.statuscode.position`.

I tried this:

```
def self.closed
  self.statuscode.position = ActsAsTenant.current_tenant.request_closed
end
```

But, that gives this error:

```
undefined method `statuscode'
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your method is a `class method`. It means that your code is referring to the class via `self` object.

```
def self.closed
  self.statuscode.position = ActsAsTenant.current_tenant.request_closed
end
```

`self` here is `class Worequest` and it doesn't have an attribute `statuscode`.

What are you trying to with `self.statuscode.position = ActsAsTenant.current_tenant.request_closed`?

Comment: The statuscode position field denotes the workflow progression of a request.  For instance 1=new, 2=open, 3=task assigned, 4= work completed, 5=archived.  When a new statuscode is added it gets a higher ID, but the app lets you sort the statuscodes. So, the new one might then become 3=waiting on approval, and the current 3 becomes 4 on down the line.

Comment: The Tenant record indicates which statuscode is for closed.  Therefore any statuscode < than that would open.